# Context Values not passing to a field with onchange property

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am trying to pass context values to a form 'A'. The fields on form 'A ' have property as onchange. Now if I delete the onchnaghege propert from that field , the values gets passed otherwise the values are unable to pass. I have no idea how to p[ass the values to fields haviung onchnge propperty. I do need to retain the ionchnege property with the fields to avoid the frlaws. My python code is below:

```
 def creates(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        for id in ids:
            deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
            my_id=int(deg_obj.my_products)
        prr= int(deg_obj.categg_temp)
        pch= int(deg_obj.categ_temps)
        cch= int(deg_obj.categ_temp2)
        print pch
        print prr
        ctx = dict(context)
        ctx.update({'default_ch':pch,'default_pr':prr})
        return{
              'view_type': 'form',
              'view_mode': 'form',
              'res_model': 'product.product',
              'context':ctx,
              'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
              'nodestroy':False,
              'target': 'current',
              }
```

My xml code contains tyhose fields where I am trying to set tyhe values :

```
   <label for="pr" string="Parent"  />
            <field name="pr" domain="[('parent_id','=',False)]" on_change="myTop_Category_OnChange(pr)"/>


   <label for="ch" string="Category" />
        <field name="ch" domain="[('parent_id','=',1)]" on_change="myProduct_Category_OnChange(ch)" />
```

I need guidance on this .

Answer (score 1):

I fear I don't understand you question but I'll try to answer it ;)

If you try to get the value of 'pr' field in the 'myProduct_Category_OnChange' method, you need to declare the on_change statement like this:

```
on_change="myProduct_Category_OnChange(ch, pr)"
```

Comment: I am trying to say is that the field 'cr' is not getting updated with the value. I am very much sure that its because of the onchange method defined with the 'pr' field.

Comment: Can you give me the code of your on_change method ?